# MongoDB: sort collection A using collection B property and vice versa

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have collection A that have properties :

- subscriptionPlan:string
- businessId:string

collection B properties:

- name:string
- createdAt:number
- businessId:string

how do I sort by: name, createdAt, and subscriptionPlan ?

Comment: I think you will need to show us the command and sample document that is being retrieved. Are you using a `$lookup` to combine information from the two collections together into the documents that are returned to the client and need to be sorted?

Comment: Please provide few sample documents and the requested result from this them